# div resize with jquery failes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to resize my div "container" with jquery and i think i understood howto do this. but unfortunately, ist doesn't work. here's my simple code:

```
var viewport = $( window ).height();
var container_height = viewport - 125;
alert("setting height to "+container_height);
$( "#container" ).height(container_height);
alert("height is now " + $( "#container" ).height());
```

the first alert tells me the correct height, but the second tells me, it's null.

what's wrong there?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, try this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){

    var viewport = $( window ).height();

    var container_height = viewport - 125;

    $( "#container" ).height(container_height);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8z7wzk1p/

Answer (score 0):

it works here  [**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hk6azx6m/)

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**css**

```
#container{

    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:Yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    var viewport = $(window).height();
    var container_height = viewport - 125;
    alert("setting height to " + container_height);
    $("#container").height(container_height);
    alert("height is now " + $("#container").height());

});
```